Does every function in $S_{(f)}$ have a representation of the form $\frac{g}{f^d}$ for $g \in S$ of degree $d$?
Let $S$ be a graded ring and $\mathfrak{p}$ a homogeneous prime ideal in $S$, then define $S_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ as the subring of elements of degree $0$ in the localization $S_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
In the proof of Theorem I.3.4 (a), stating that for a projective variety $Y \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$, the ring of global regular functions $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ is the ground field $k$, Hartshorne begins by observing that for a global regular function $f$, we must have $f \in S(Y)_{(x_i)}$.
However, he then goes on to say that this means $f$ can be written as $\frac{g_i}{x_i^{N_i}}$ for $g_i \in S(Y)$ of degree $N_i$. This seems counter-intuitive to me, because I expect the elements in the localization $S_{x_i}$ to look like quotients by polynomials that are explicitly not generated by $x_i$.
From where do we get the fact that every function in $S_{(f)}$ has a representation of the form $\frac{g}{f^d}$ for $g \in S$ of degree $d$? Is it completely obvious?

You're getting turned around here. The notation $S(Y)_{(x_i)}$ is being used here for the homogeneous localization, which is defined as the degree-zero subring of $S(Y)_{x_i}$, the localization of $S(Y)$ with respect to the element $x_i$, where the homogeneous elements of $S(Y)_{x_i}$ are those of the form $\frac{s}{x_i^n}$ with $s$ homogeneous, and $\deg \frac{s}{x_i^n}=\deg s - n$ (see the last sentence before theorem I.3.4 on page 18, or proposition II.2.5 on page 76-77 for this definition). This gives the statement Hartshorne is using: every element of the homogeneous localization $S(Y)_{(x_i)}$ has a representative of the form $\frac{s}{x_i^n}$ where $s\in S(Y)$ is homogeneous and $\deg s = n$.

I think what I am not quite understanding is why the (homogeneous) elements of $S(Y)_{x_i}$ are of the form $\frac{s}{\color{red} {x_i^n}}$. Isn't the localization with respect to $S(Y) {\color{red} {\setminus (x_i)}}$? How do we know there is such a representation with $x_i$ in the denominator?

No. We are taking the localization with respect to the element $x_i$, i.e. the multiplicative system we're using is ${1,x_i,x_i^2,\cdots}$. (There's no guarantee $(x_i)$ is prime, which is necessary for $S(Y)\setminus (x_i)$ to be a multiplicative system.)

On p. 18, Hartshorne says when defining $S_{(\mathfrak{p})}$: "[...] with respect to the multiplicative subset $T$ consisting of the homogeneous elements of $S$ not in $\mathfrak{p}$". Doesn't that mean, $S(Y)_{x_i} := (S(Y) \setminus (x_i))^{-1}~S(Y)$? I apologize if I am somehow misunderstanding something completely basic!

Again, as in my last comment, there is no guarantee that $(x_i)$ is a prime ideal. And even if Hartshorne wanted to specify that, he'd need to write $S(Y){((x_i))}$. Anyways, read to the end of the same paragraph you are referencing to see that "[s]imilarly, if $f\in S$ is a homogeneous element, we denote by $S{(f)}$ the subring of elements of degree zero in the localized ring $S_f$." For what it's worth, this is a bit of a standard confusion, so no need to apologize.

I understand now, thank you. The cause for my confusion was my unfamiliarity with the notation $R_t$ for localization in contexts other than localization by prime ideals.
